# Jquery countdown timer for week days only

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

I am using Syotimer jquery plugin(https://github.com/mrfratello/SyoTimer) for recursive countdown. It is working fine.Currently I have set it to peroidic countdown for 2 days.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#periodic_timer').syotimer({
                year: 2016,
                month: 1,
                day: 30,
                hour: 13,
                minute: 41,


                dayVisible: false,
                dubleNumbers: false,
               // effectType: 'opacity',

                periodUnit: 'd',
                periodic: true,
                periodInterval: 2,
            });
```

Now my problem is i need to s**et the timer on only week day and on weekend the timer should not work**?
          Can anyone help me on this? Does this plugin provide such feature or is there any possible way that i can achieve my requirement?

Regards,
aton1004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functionality not necessarily include in the plugin. You can determine the current day of the week and then, if it is not weekend, just connect the plugin:

```
var currentDateTime = new Date(),
    currentWeekDay = currentDateTime.getDay();

if ( currentWeekDay != 0 && currentWeekDay != 6 ) {
    var syoTimerOptions = {
        // put here plugin options
        };
    jQuery('#periodic_timer').syotimer( syoTimerOptions );
}
```

P.S.: Method getDate() returns number of week day: 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday, ..., 6 - Saturday